# How to show vertices on a cube when selected in Unity (during runtime)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cube, vertices

I'm trying to write a script that makes a cube turn blue and display the vertices of the cube on it when selected during runtime. So basically when clicked, it will show all the vertices and then allow a user to select different vertices of the cube.

This is what i have so far, essentially only turning the cube blue. How can I display vertices of the cube as spheres? I want to be able to select these vertices later.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Cube : MonoBehaviour {
    void OnMouseDown() {
        Renderer rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        rend.material.color = Color.blue;
        //insert method to display vertices
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you finding the vertices of your 'cube' ? and what are you using as 'spheres' ? Unity primitives?

Comment: @LOLslowSTi I haven't found the vertices, I assumed they were in some sort of array as a property of the cube. I would like to use  unity primitives as the spheres. (I'm new to unity so I may be saying this wrong, pointing me in the right direction of where to look would be appreciated)

Comment: What is the 'cube' is it also a primitive?

Comment: Yes it's also a primitive

Comment: You can get an array of `Vector3`s of the vertices of your models with GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.vertices (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-vertices.html). "Displaying vertices" is open to a very wide interpretation. Are you thinking of writing some shader code that will render a wireframe of a model, with a color-filled circle around each vertex? "Selecting the vertices" by mouse could be done by either raycasting (shoot it at a vertex which you give a small circle-collider around) or writing custom code for selecting stuff based on x/y mouse coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since both the cube and spheres are primitives:

you find the vertices like this (assuming `cube` is a `GameObject`):

```
Vector3[] vertices = cube.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.vertices;
```

And then to create your spheres (need `using System.Linq`):

```
GameObject[] spheres = vertices.Select(vert =>
{
    GameObject sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere)
    sphere.transform.position = vert;
    return sphere;
})
.ToArray();
```

UPDATE: Okay i see your problem with too many vertices now, and this is how i would do it, and i would personally make threshold be the radius of your spheres, so that once the spheres begin overlapping they just become one:

```
float threshold = 0.1f;

public void CreateSpheres()
{
    List<GameObject> spheres = new List<GameObject>();
    foreach (Vector3 vert in vertices)
    {
        if (spheres.Any(sph => (sph.transform.position - vert) < threshold)) continue;

        GameObject sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere)
        sphere.transform.position = vert;
        spheres.Add(sphere);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have the variable `cube` as a `GameObject` I'm not sure how to do so. I tried defining cube like this: `GameObject cube = this.gameObject;` But then when I write `Vector3[] vertices = cube.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.vertices;` I get the error Cannot implicitly convert between type `Unity.Engine.MeshFilter` and `Unity.Engine.Vector3[ ]`

Comment: if your typing this from inside a `MonoBehaviour` then you have to write `gameObject` instead of `cube` like this: `gameObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.vertices;` should work.

Comment: That works however the `vertices.Select` gives me an error type arguments  for method 'Enumerable.Select<TSource, TResult> Cannot be inferred from the usage' in Visual Studio. In Unity this error comes up 'error CS1643: Not all code paths return a value in anonymous method of type `System.Func<TSource,TResult>'

Comment: Found the error, updated. Dont know how i missed that return statement.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't get the Select Function to work as show in one of the previous example. The coordinates were found using `GetComponent<MeshFilter>.mesh.vertices;` as described in the other answer.

```
void OnMouseDown() {
    Renderer rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    rend.material.color = Color.blue;
    Vector3[] vertices = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.vertices;
    Vector3[] verts = removeDuplicates(vertices);
    drawSpheres(verts);
}
```

The vertices array contains 24 elements for the reason shown [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/143109/why-does-a-primitive-cube-contain-24-verts.html). So the function removeDuplicates was written to get rid of the duplicate vertices. This function is shown below:

```
Vector3[] removeDuplicates(Vector3[] dupArray) {

    Vector3[] newArray = new Vector3[8];  //change 8 to a variable dependent on shape
    bool isDup = false;
    int newArrayIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dupArray.Length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < newArray.Length; j++) {
            if (dupArray[i] == newArray[j]) {
                isDup = true;
            }
        }
        if (!isDup) {
            newArray[newArrayIndex] = dupArray[i];
            newArrayIndex++;
            isDup = false;
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Lastly the Spheres were drawn using the new verts Array using the drawSpheres function shown here:

```
void drawSpheres(Vector3[] verts) {
    GameObject[] Spheres = new GameObject[verts.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < verts.Length; i++) {
        Spheres[i] = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
        Spheres[i].transform.position = verts[i];
        Spheres[i].transform.localScale -= new Vector3(0.8F, 0.8F, 0.8F);
    }
}
```